# Getting Exit-Flag: 0,2 with SQP algorithm of fmincon Matlab function

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, solver

I have a large scale multi objective optimization problem  to solve with `fmincon` solver of `Matlab`. I tried different solver to get a better and faster output. Here is the challenge:

I am getting `Exit Flag: 1,0,4,5` for different Pareto points ,as it is a multi-objective optimization problem, with `Active-set algorithm`. Then I tried to check different algorithms like `interior-point` and `sqp` for generating the Pareto points. I observed that `sqp` returns few `exit flags 1`, some `2` and few `0` but not any `4` or `5` `flag`. Also, I should note that, its `0` and `2` flagged solutions are correct answers . However, When it comes to return any `exit flag` except `1`, it takes a long time to solve the Pareto point.

As `interior-point` algorithm is designed for large scale program, it's very faster than `sqp` in generating the Pareto solutions. However, it only returns solutions with `Exit flag 0`. Unfortunately, its `0` flagged solutions are wrong solutions despite  `sqp` which its `0` and `2` flagged solutions are correct answers.
0) Is there anyway to config the `fmincon` to solve my problem with `interior-point` and also get the correct solutions? In the literature I saw some problems similar to mine have been solved with `interior-point` algorithm.

1) Is there any settings `(TolX,TolCon,...)` that I can use to get more `exit flag 1` ?

2) Is there any setting that speeds up the optimization process with the cost of lower accuracy?

3) For 2 Pareto points I am getting exit flag -2 , which means the problem is not feasible for them. It is expected from the nature of the problem. But it takes ages for `fmincon` to determine the  Exit-Flag -2.  Is there any option that I can set to satisfy 1,2 and also leave this infeasible point faster? 
I couldn't do this , because I can only set options for one time and all Pareto points should use the same option.

To describe the problem I should say:
I have several linear and nonlinear `(.^2,Sin...)` for both equality and inequality constraints (about `300`) and also having `400` optimization variables. All objective functions of this multi-objective optimization problem is linear.

these are the options that I currently use. Please help me to modify it

```
 options = optimset('Algorithm', 'sqp', 'Display', 'off'); 

 options = optimset('Algorithm', 'sqp', 'Display', 'off', 'TolX',1e-6,...
  'TolFun',1e-6,'MaxIter',1e2, 'MaxFunEvals', 1e4);
```

First option takes about `500 sec` for generating `15` Pareto points. Meaning that each optimization of `fmincon` expend `33 sec`.
The second option takes `200 sec`, which is `13 sec` for each optimization of `fmincon`.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the Optimization Toolbox? As I understand your problem is linear in objectives (and potentially non-linear in functions / constraints), if so you might want to consider taking a look at: 
- fgoalattain (you will need to re-write your problem into an equivalent goal-seek format with matrix inputs) 
- gamultiobj (uses genetic optimization to solve multi-objective problems)

Difficult to predict how these methods will perform, but at least this could open more options to try out

Comment: I wrote my own multi objective optimization method (NBI,epsilon constraint, modified epsilon constraint.) In these method (also in your proposed fgoalattain), `fmincon` must find a solution for each Pareto point. The problem is , fmincon gets in trap for some points and return 0 and 2 exit flag. But, using sqp algothim in fmincon, these 0 and 2 flagged solutions  are correct answers as I know the desired out put. But if I use  `interior-point` algorithm within fmincon, it only returns exit flag 0.  ..... @AzmyRajab

Comment: ...  More over these 0 flagged solutions are not near to my desired answer. So is there a way to set up `interior-point` algorithm for my problem and also get correct solutions? Thanks for reply @AzmyRajab

Comment: It seems like your problem when tackled with Interior Point algorithm is failing to converge and is exiting at wrong answers (so not even approaching the regions of the 'correct' answers unlike sqp).

Assuming the set-up you have is fine, two suggestions:
 
- Do you happen to know the Hessian for your problem? If you do (or can easily calculate it) providing this will help 'steer' the algorithm towards the regions of correct solutions

- Are you providing arbitrary starting points? If you have an idea what the answers should be - try setting that as initial point and check

Comment: Assuming that, when initialized at or near the true solutions, fmincon set to interior point does converge, then at least we know its definitely a matter of convergence / initialization.  

What you can do then is run a few iterations of another method for a rough / approximate solution, and use those rough answers as initial points for Interior Point. Hopefully this layered approach is fast / efficient enough for your usage. 

Thought this link may be quite helpful as well:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-fails.html