# How to define SPARSE matrices for linear constraints?

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, sparse-matrix

I am solving a constrained optimization problem using `fmincon` solver with `sqp` algorithm. 
The linear equality and inequality matrices I have, are rather sparse. I was wonder how can I define the following `Aeq` and `Beq` matrices in sparse form in order to speed up the calculation?
Best regards

```
cons1=[eye(10),-eye(10),zeros(10,5*19),-eye(10),zeros(10,280)]; 
cons2=[zeros(19,20),eye(19),-eye(19),zeros(19,19*2),-eye(19),zeros(19,290)];
cons3=[zeros(19,96),diag(tan_fid),zeros(19,10),-eye(19),zeros(19,261)];
cons4=[zeros(19,58),-eye(19),-eye(19),eye(19),zeros(19,290)];
% #### linear_eq=Aeq*X'-Beq; ####
Aeq=[cons1;cons2;cons3;cons4];
Beq=[-pga ; -pda ;zeros(19,1); zeros(19,1)];
```

Comment: Did you try simply using the `sparse` command on each matrix?

Comment: Would you tell me how please? I dont know sparse commands! @rayryeng

Comment: It's just `Aeq = sparse(Aeq); Beq = sparse(Beq);`  you've already set up the constraints and it does look like they're highly sparse..... So just use the `sparse` function to transform into such.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote them as you said `Aeq =sparse(Aeq),...`. But I am receiving the following warning `Warning: Cannot use sparse matrices with sqp algorithm: converting to full. ` Which means `sqp` algorithm in `fmincon` cannot handle sparse matrices. Also I have problems regarding to use other solvers (that may accept Sparse matrices) as explained [here] [1] . Any Idea @rayryeng ?  
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237483/how-to-avoid-getting-exit-flag-2-and-0-using-fmincon-and-which-solver-suits-my-d